# Insert result of select statement to another table in Oracle stored porcedures

Tags: oracle, select, stored-procedures, plsql, insert-into

I want to use the following stored procedure to insert data into a table which is contains information about tablespaces free space.

Using only INSERT INTO statement without procedures compilation is working fine, but however I compile the procedure, it isn't working.

Below is the sample stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERTSPACEINFO(
       TABLESPACE_NAME IN SPACEINFO.TABLESPACE_NAME%TYPE,
       TSIZE IN SPACEINFO.TSIZE%TYPE,
       FREESIZE IN SPACEINFO.FREESIZE%TYPE,
       SYSDATE IN SPACEINFO.INSERT_DATE%TYPE)


IS
BEGIN  

INSERT into SYS.Spaceinfo (TABLESPACE_NAME, TSIZE, FREESIZE, INSERT_DATE)
(SELECT
  df.tablespace_name AS "Tablespace",
  df.bytes / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) AS "TSIZE",
  Trunc(fs.bytes / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)) AS "FREESIZE",
  SYSDATE
FROM (
  SELECT tablespace_name
    ,Sum(bytes) AS bytes
  FROM dba_free_space
  GROUP BY tablespace_name
  ) fs,
  (
    SELECT tablespace_name,
    SUM(bytes) AS bytes
    FROM dba_data_files
    GROUP BY tablespace_name
    ) df,
    dual

WHERE fs.tablespace_name = df.tablespace_name);

COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Do you get compile time errors?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code works for me. If it's not working for you, it's probably because you did *not* compile or recompile the procedure between edits. BTW, you might want to send this code over to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). I recommend you create objects in a schema other than SYS.

Comment: @J Versler, What is the error?

Comment: Hi! I have a trouble with SYS.Spaceinfo table. The procedure has compiled successfully, but no data has written to the table. All columns types in this table is varchar2(20).

Comment: Here are the first three things that I noticed in that procedure declaration: 1. Using of system reserved words, such as `SYSDATE` shouldn't be allowed (you're using it as a parameter). 2. What's the schema where you declared this procedure ? (Does it have a synonym for SYS.Spaceinfo) I ask, because you use for instance `TABLESPACE_NAME IN SPACEINFO.TABLESPACE_NAME%TYPE`, which should have either READ rights or a synonym in the same schema (if not, just declare it as `TABLESPACE_NAME IN SYS.SPACEINFO.TABLESPACE_NAME%TYPE`. 3. You don't need IN PArameters for this Procedure. 4.* No Exceptions.